# How do I run scala sbt behind a zsacaler proxy (zscloud)

Tags: windows-7, proxy, scala

My company recently used new security software from zscaler to secure internet traffic.
From my basic understanding, what it does is:
It takes all encrypted SSL internet connections and looks into it for harmful transmissions and god knows what, acting as a 'man in the middle'.
Now, when I open a website in a browser, for a split second I see sometimes that it switches to https://login.zscloud.net/...  followed by some cryptic numbers and the website I originally wanted.

Since this runs, scala sbt doesn't, because it can't connect to any repository anymore.

I've read a lot of posts and tried many things for more than 3 days:

- I configured the Proxy settings for http and https in sbtconfig.txt
- I imported the root-certificates for our proxy into the java keystore with 
  certain variants (keystore in jdk or jre).
- I tried versions 0.13.8 and 1.2.8 of sbt

The essential error message from sbt is:

java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /IP-OF-MY-CORPORATE-PROXY:8080

But when I copy for example "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom" from the error output an put it into a browser, it opens without problems.

I run scala and sbt on a Windows 7 machine using Version 1.8.0_201 for Java and JDK.

Has anybody some experience with this zscaler/proxy thing and sbt?

Any help would be appreciated, even hints on how to check or debug the connection to the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, I got it working again:

1.) When my company switched to zscaler, the traffic was not running thru the proxy any more. The browser was configured automaticaly, so i did not found out directly. Unfortunately the proxy was still on, but did not work properly any more.
So I deleted all entries regarding a proxy in sbtconfig.txt. I still had to specify the keystore and the password for it

2.) The root certificate for my company is somehow corrupt or at least not sufficient, I had to import the next certificate in the chain into the keystore, then it worked.